# Lightning Sync with Gmail - But user is using gmail through Outlook app on PC

Tags: lightning, salesforce-for-outlook, gmail

We have just setup Lightning sync for Gmail, and it is working well. However, some of our reps are using the Outlook application on a PC (with Gmail IMAP) and want to use the Salesforce sidebar.

During the setup process, you ultimately get to a point when it looks for an Exchange account and can't find one because the rep is using gmail.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use this setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe any of the Salesforce Outlook integration tools will work. They all require Exchange. LinkPoint's Outlook integration works directly with Outlook and will support any email server Outlook is utilizing. You can find more information about LinkPoint on the [AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001qTIuEAM).

Comment: Are you affiliated with this service or product?